# Huge chin appears on top of the application window

Tags: android, statusbar, sipdroid

I am editing [Sipdroid](https://github.com/i-p-tel/sipdroid) and making changes to the UI, but every single activity in this application has a huge chin on top which I can't seem to hide in any way. It looks like it's recognized as the status bar, as you can see from the code that I've shared below, but also by the fact that whenever I change the status bar color, the chin turns to that color as well. As of now, the only way I've found for it to not create padding on top of the screen is to add `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` to the style XML.
The following is the code for both the layout XML file and the Kotlin class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
package org.sipdroid.sipua.ui

import android.app.Activity
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.Window
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import org.sipdroid.sipua.R

class TestActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)

        val btn = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.hello)
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            // gets the status bar height
            val rectangle = Rect()
            window.decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle)
            val statusBarHeight = rectangle.top
            val contentViewTop = window.findViewById<View>(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).top
            val titleBarHeight = contentViewTop - statusBarHeight

            // makes the TextView as high as the status bar,
            // so we have a visual representation of the
            // actual height with layout bounds visible
            btn.height = statusBarHeight

            Toast.makeText(
                this@TestActivity,
                "$statusBarHeight $titleBarHeight ${rectangle.height()}",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }
}
```

[These](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VomGo.jpg) are screenshots both with and without layout bounds shown.

Comment: Add getActionBar().hide() in the onCreate before setContentView()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got this solved messing around with stuff and turned out the only thing I needed to do was to remove the following piece of code from the Manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `getActionBar().hide()` in the onCreate method before setContentView()